# YapDatabase memory consumption on fts index update

Tags: yapdatabase

I´ve done some changes to my YapDatabase-fts-index, by adding a some columns and updated the versionTag.

Now, when starting up the database, yap runs through all relevant rows in order to rebuild the index, as expected.

But while doing this, memory allocations keeps increasing until the app crashes - before the fts-index rebuild completes.

My dataset is about 100k rows, where each row has 3 columns containing about 2-3 short words.

I verified the memory usage with a simple handler block:

```
let block = YapDatabaseFullTextSearchHandler.withObjectBlock { (dict: NSMutableDictionary, collection: String, key: String, object: AnyObject) -> Void in

     dict.setObject("123 234 345", forKey: "1")
     dict.setObject("456 567 678", forKey: "2")

}
```

Is this a bug in Yap? Is adding fts-columns not supported? Should I consider adding a new index for the additional fts-columns?